# SQL CE 4.0 Error - ReleaseHandleFailed was detected

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I keep getting this error in the dev environment - 'A SafeHandle or CriticalHandle of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.HasSafeHandle' failed to properly release the handle with value ...."

It is in a VS 2012 Winforms application and only seems to happen if a particular piece of code is run at some point. The error shows after the form is closed, but I can't understand why. It only happens in the dev environment and seems to be OK in the compiled version, but I don't want to just ignore it.

The error seems to be caused by this line of code, although weirdly at this point in time I have not opened a connection to the SQL ce database and the directory it is searching in does not have the SQL ce database in it. It is mearly reading in txt files that match a pattern

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(importDirectory, "BucketHistory*.txt")
```

I'll do some more digging tomorrow, it's late now, and I have no idea what is causing it.
Any pointers ??!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was having a bit of brain fade yesterday. Been working too long hours !
For anyone interested, the problem was that I was opening a connection, then copying the file and running a shrink whilst the connection was still open. It had nothing to do with that line of code. 
I would have expected the copy to have thrown an exception, but it didn't appear to. Oh, and opening *another* connection inside the using statement of the first one. Sigh.